# Java выполнение условий цикла for

Tags: java

```
if (условие1 && условие2){};
```

и

```
if (условие1) {if (условие2){}};
```

что будет оптимальнее? то есть всмысле в первом примере если условие1 ложно, условие2 будет проверятся? или лучше все таки второй пример использовать?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Оптимальным является первый вариант. Если в `if` 2 логических утверждения связанные `and`, то при невыполнении 1-го (левого условия) второе не проверяется. Именно поэтому часто принято писать:

```
if(object!=null && object.getValue()==1)
   System.out.println("Bingo!");
```

что является более экономным чем:

```
if(object!=null) {
    if(object.getValue()==1)
       System.out.println("Bingo!");
}
```

Подозреваю, что с точки зрения генерируемого байткода оба варианта эквивалентны, но читаемость и синтаксический сахар никто не отменял.